# Spring Cloud Dataflow Task database configuration

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to understand the expected behavior when running Batch tasks via Spring Cloud Dataflow wrt datasource configuration.

Is the idea that the Spring Batch database tables (BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, etc.) would be in the SCDF database itself?  There appears to be some magic happening when launching a task via SCDF where it creates those tables in the SCDF database and appears to use them.  It seems to be injecting the SCDF datasource into my application?

I'm currently running on the localhost server version 2.0.1.  Streams are working as expected, they use the datasource configured in application.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the idea that the Spring Batch database tables (BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, etc.) would be in the SCDF database itself?

Correct. It is required that the Spring Batch, Task, and SCDF share a common datasource if you are interested in tracking and managing the lifecycle of batch-jobs using the SCDF Shell/Dashboard.

If you include a batch-job in the Task application, it is the application that directly creates the Batch and Task schemas when it starts. SCDF doesn't inject datasource creds unless you intentionally request for it to do that when it launches the Tasks.

SCDF happens to partake in the same datasource, so it can in turn query the executions/status tables to show it in the Dashboard.

Here's some more background in the [ref. guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sharing-spring-cloud-dataflows-datastore-with-tasks).